# sql select from multiple records only the most recent

Tags: sql-server

i have a table named customer_age that loks like this:

```
ID     1   2    3     4     5    6     7     8     9

NAME  JIM  JIM  JIM  NICK  NICK  NICK  Paul  Paul  Paul                                       
VALUE  20  13   12    10    20    8     4     24    14
```

and i want to display only the first record from each name. Something like this

```
ID     1     4      7    

NAME  JIM  NICK   Paul                                  
VALUE  20   10      4
```

So far i have not been able to work it out. 
i use sql server 2005
Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I assume "first record" means the one with the lowest ID?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using a subselect to find the lowest ID for each name, and use that set of IDs to pull the records from the main table:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Value
FROM customer_age
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID
    FROM customer_age
    GROUP BY Name
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just select the first record for each name using `cross apply`:

```
SELECT 
ca.ID, ca.NAME, ca.VALUE
FROM customer_age c
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ID, NAME, VALUE 
       FROM customer_age ca 
       WHERE ca.NAME = c.NAME ORDER BY ID) ca
ORDER BY ca.ID
```

Comment: This gives repeated results, 3 rows in customer_age join with the 1 row returned from the apply.

Answer (score 2):

How about using window functions??

```
SELECT Id, Name, Value
FROM (
    SELECT Id, Name, Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Id ASC) AS rowNum
    FROM customer_age
) AS sub
WHERE rowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming first record means highest ID, you may try your query with descending orderby ID and TOP n.