# Select recent record from multiple within same query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

My question is very related to [sql select from multiple records only the most recent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295758/sql-select-from-multiple-records-only-the-most-recent), although it is simply not working.

I have a `view`, getting the member name and their current rank number.
I also have a table, which finds all the rank names greater than the said rank number.

As-is, the new view shows the current member, as well as their rank title `>=` that in the rank title table.

This means the output displays every title after their rank, whereas I only want to show the first (earliest) one.

I have tried a modified example from the above link like so:

```
SELECT dbo.vwGetMemberRank.siteMemberId AS ID
     , dbo.vwGetMemberRank.memberNickname AS Nick
     , dbo.vwGetMemberRank.siteMemberRankLevel AS currentPoints
     , dbo.tblSiteMemberRankTitle.siteMemberRankLevel AS neededPoints
     , dbo.tblSiteMemberRankTitle.siteMemberRankTitle AS rankTitle
FROM dbo.vwGetMemberRank 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblSiteMemberRankTitle
        ON dbo.vwGetMemberRank.siteMemberRankLevel >= dbo.tblSiteMemberRankTitle.siteMemberRankLevel

WHERE dbo.vwGetMemberRank.siteMemberId IN
                 (
                   SELECT  MIN(siteMemberId) AS ID
                   FROM dbo.vwGetMemberRank AS vwGetMemberRank_1
                   GROUP BY siteMemberRankLevel
                  )
```

This is still displaying every other title.

**Edit**

*vwGetMemberRank*

```
SELECT dbo.tblSiteMemberRank.siteMemberId
     , dbo.tblSiteMemberRank.siteMemberRankLevel
     , dbo.tblSiteMemberDetail.memberNickname
FROM dbo.tblSiteMemberDetail 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblSiteMemberRank ON dbo.tblSiteMemberDetail.siteMemberId = dbo.tblSiteMemberRank.siteMemberId
```

*tblSiteMemberRankTitle*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSiteMemberRankTitle](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [siteMemberRankTitle] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [siteMemberRankDescription] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [siteMemberRankLevel] [int] NULL,
    [thumbnailLocation] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__tblSiteM__3213E83F1B0907CE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Did you check out LAG() and LEAD()?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx

Comment: Never heard of that. Will read up on it now. - Could you maybe provide an example in the interim?

Comment: Basically you create a window / offset to say that "I want the result of this function, for a row this far away from me, when I order all rows like this". This is very efficient since you don't have to self-join anything; you just reuse the set you have in your FROM clause.

Comment: Can you post your (relevant) data structure. I think this can be resolved using `ROW_NUMBER`, or `OUTER APPLY`, but am still not quite 100% on your criteria

Comment: updated, hope that is enough

Comment: And to clarify you want to get each member's lowest ever rank?

Comment: The current displays all the ranks up till the users 'supposed-to-be' current one. So I want the highest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to order the ranks in whatever order you like (I've used `dbo.tblSiteMemberRankTitle.siteMemberRankLevel DESC`), then limit  the results to where the RowNumber is 1, thus only getting the row with the highest `siteMemberRankLevel` for each SiteMemberID (PARTITION BY)

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT dbo.vwGetMemberRank.siteMemberId AS ID
         , dbo.vwGetMemberRank.memberNickname AS Nick
         , dbo.vwGetMemberRank.siteMemberRankLevel AS currentPoints
         , dbo.tblSiteMemberRankTitle.siteMemberRankLevel AS neededPoints
         , dbo.tblSiteMemberRankTitle.siteMemberRankTitle AS rankTitle
         , RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dbo.vwGetMemberRank.siteMemberId ORDER BY dbo.tblSiteMemberRankTitle.siteMemberRankLevel DESC)
    FROM    dbo.vwGetMemberRank 
            INNER JOIN dbo.tblSiteMemberRankTitle
                ON tblSiteMemberRankTitle.siteMemberRankLevel >= dbo.vwGetMemberRank.siteMemberRankLevel
)
SELECT  ID, Nick, CurrentPoints, NeededPoints, RankTitle
FROM    CTE
WHERE   RowNumber = 1;
```

Comment: That seems to work great, except I need a rank for every member. This is only showing the very first member listed.

Comment: Have you removed the where clause from your query (`WHERE dbo.vwGetMemberRank.siteMemberId IN (SELECT  MIN(siteMemberId) AS ID...`), if not this could be the cause.

Comment: Yeah, I basically copy+pasted that. :P

Comment: Apologies, think I've just seen the error, I had `=` in the join instead of `>=`

Comment: Working perfectly! Although, just change `>=` to `<=`